# /dev/shm is full at 100% use, but has no large files

Tags: ram

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04.3 (kernel 5.11.0-34-generic #36~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP), so this may be a bug. After a few hours of use the shared memory partition fills up.  According to `df`, partition `/dev/shm` has 16G of data in it:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
tmpfs                       16G   16G     0 100% /dev/shm
...
```

Trying to write a new file to that partition fails:

```
$ echo "foobar" > /dev/shm/foobar.txt
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

However, when I look at the files in that partition, the files only use around 170K:

```
$ du -h /dev/shm/*
0   /dev/shm/foobar.txt
4.0K    /dev/shm/sem.CiscoAcMemoryLock
4.0K    /dev/shm/sem.CiscoAcNamedEventNVM
4.0K    /dev/shm/sem.CiscoAcNamedEventOpenDNS
4.0K    /dev/shm/sem.CiscoAcNamedEventPostureISE
156K    /dev/shm/tmp
```

I notice this happening because google-chrome dumps core, and I can't restart Chrome until there is space in `/dev/shm`, and the only I've found to way to get the memory back is reboot.

How can I find out what is using space in /dev/shm?

Comment: After trial and error, I found this was caused by google-chrome.   I'm able to work around it by running Chrome with the "--disable-dev-shm-usage" option.  I'm still interested in answers which could have pointed out Chrome as the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Files exist on a filesystem as long as they still have a directory entry *or* are being kept open by a current process. Running `du -h /dev/shm/` (adding the `*` excludes files beginning with `.`) will only show the former.

You also need to run `sudo lsof /dev/shm`, which shows the currently open files on that filesystem.

For example:

```
COMMAND      PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
QtWebEngi 654092 user  DEL    REG   0,31          2610 /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.eAzBpJ
QtWebEngi 654092 user  DEL    REG   0,31          2613 /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.eY7oKn
QtWebEngi 654092 user  DEL    REG   0,31          2624 /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.zuBEOF
QtWebEngi 654092 user   22u   REG   0,31      144 2610 /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.eAzBpJ (deleted)
QtWebEngi 654092 user   29u   REG   0,31      144 2613 /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.eY7oKn (deleted)
QtWebEngi 654092 user   46r   REG   0,31  1048576 2624 /dev/shm/.org.chromium.Chromium.zuBEOF (deleted)
```

Lines that end with `(deleted)` won't be found by `du`, but will still take up space as long as any process is holding on to that file.

Comment: Good suggestion, and I'm sure this will be useful for others, but for me, when I kill all processes that show up with the lsof command, and lsof shows nothing attached to /dev/shm, and the /dev/shm directory is complete empty,  df shows that partion at 100% full.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (kernel version 5.11.0.34.36, updated with updater to 5.11.0.36.40). After updating kernel to latest version, was problem solved. By post from Marc Gil Sendra, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654004/ubuntu-20-04-problems-with-chrome-teams-visual-studio-code-maybe-related-wi from 14.7.2021 he solve problem with updating kernel to 5.12.10 version. I use https://linuxhint.com/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/ to upgrade version to 5.14.8-051408-generic and problem seems to be solved.